# How to supply value to jquery ajax variable via a FORM?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

How can the following be modified so *forminput* is a textarea form box that accepts user input, rather than hard coded as it is now?

Once the form is submitted, it will populate forminput in the following code:

```
data: JSON.stringify({json:*forminput*}),
```

In the textarea box, data will be pasted in exactly as it is in the javascript below.

```
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#postit").on("click", function () {

            var forminput = [{
                  "field1":"100",
                  "field2":"2000",
                  "field3":"400",
                },
                {
                  "field1":"110",
                  "field2":"2200",
                  "field3":"520"
                }];


            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                url: "http://localhost/capturedata",
                data: JSON.stringify({json:forminput}),
                dataType: 'json',
                success: function (data) {

                }
            });
        });
    });
</script>
<a href="#" id="postit">Submit</a>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**The whole idea doesn't make sense** because the user might enter a value that is not valid JSON. In the question you said that *"data will be pasted in exactly as it is in the javascript below"* - but what if it isn't? Or what if the user enters something that *is* valid JSON but *isn't* remotely like the format you're expecting? The user might enter `{"this":"is valid json"}` and it would be accepted and submitted but not what your server is expecting.

Having said that, to take your requirement literally you could implement it by adding the following somewhere on your page:

```
<textarea id="forminput"></textarea>
```

And then in your JS function you could get the value with:

```
var forminput = $("#forminput").val();
```

...which would give you the value as a string. If you wanted to use that as an object exactly like you use the `forminput` variable currently shown in your question it'd need to be:

```
var forminput = $.parseJSON( $("#forminput").val() );
```

So to address my point about the user entering invalid values, you could do something like this:

```
try {
    var forminput = $.parseJSON( $("#forminput").val() );
    // use forminput
} catch (e) {
    alert("Invalid input: " + e.message);
}
```

...but even that will only catch general invalid JSON errors, it won't catch the cases where the user has entered valid JSON of the wrong format for your needs.

Answer (score 1):

If the user is pasting in values in the same format (along with the brackets and squiggly brackets), just add the following HTML

```
<textarea>

</textarea>
```

Then change

```
var forminput = [{
                  "field1":"100",
                  "field2":"2000",
                  "field3":"400",
                },
                {
                  "field1":"110",
                  "field2":"2200",
                  "field3":"520"
                }];
```

to

```
var forminput = $("textarea").val();
var forminput = $.parseJSON(forminput);
```

Comment: That won't work, because `forminput` would then be a string where it used to be an array.

Comment: @nnnnnn Oops, I thought he already had a parsejson function in there